Why "email_sender" is not active with this web app project?
package : email_sender
firebase using : yes
I want to use the sender email in my project, so package "flutter_email_sender" isn't work beacause it's not for web app , then I try another one is "email_sender" and it's for web app project, I try it but it got "somethingWrong" error like this
------------Err Pic------------------------
enter image description here
------------Err Pic------------------------
-------------sent1() function-------------------------
import 'package:email_sender/email_sender.dart';

 void sent1() async {
    EmailSender emailsender = EmailSender();
    var response =
        await emailsender.sendMessage("phuris.s@ku.th", "a", "b", "c");
    print(response["message"]);
  }

-------------sent1() function-------------------------
------------ FloatingActionButton that I want to put sent1() in-------------------
Container(
              height: size.height * 0.08,
              width: size.width * 0.2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.blue[200],
              ),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate() &&
                      selectedValue1 == "ซินเนติก") {
                    formKey.currentState?.save();
                    try {
                      String invoiceNumber = await generateInvoiceNumber();
                      await _prdetailsCollection.add({
                        "project": selectedValue4,
                        "dropdowncompany": selectedValue1,
                        "dropdowndep": selectedValue2,
                        "dropdownwork": selectedValue3,
                        "fsname": prdetails.fsnames,
                        "date_pr": _dateController.text,
                        "recommend_company": prdetails.recommendcompanypr,
                        "phone": prdetails.phones,
                        "email_pr": prdetails.emailprs,
                        "number1": tablePR1.n1,
                        "order1": tablePR1.o1,
                        "des1": tablePR1.d1,
                        "amount1": tablePR1.a1,
                        "unit1": tablePR1.u1,
                        "additonal1": tablePR1.add1,
                        "number2": tablePR2.n2,
                        "order2": tablePR2.o2,
                        "des2": tablePR2.d2,
                        "amount2": tablePR2.a2,
                        "unit2": tablePR2.u2,
                        "additonal2": tablePR2.add2,
                        "number3": tablePR3.n3,
                        "order3": tablePR3.o3,
                        "des3": tablePR3.d3,
                        "amount3": tablePR3.a3,
                        "unit3": tablePR3.u3,
                        "additonal3": tablePR3.add3,
                        "number4": tablePR4.n4,
                        "order4": tablePR4.o4,
                        "des4": tablePR4.d4,
                        "amount4": tablePR4.a4,
                        "unit4": tablePR4.u4,
                        "additonal4": tablePR4.add4,
                        "number5": tablePR5.n5,
                        "order5": tablePR5.o5,
                        "des5": tablePR5.d5,
                        "amount5": tablePR5.a5,
                        "unit5": tablePR5.u5,
                        "additonal5": tablePR5.add5,
                        "number6": tablePR6.n6,
                        "order6": tablePR6.o6,
                        "des6": tablePR6.d6,
                        "amount6": tablePR6.a6,
                        "unit6": tablePR6.u6,
                        "additonal6": tablePR6.add6,
                        "number7": tablePR7.n7,
                        "order7": tablePR7.o7,
                        "des7": tablePR7.d7,
                        "amount7": tablePR7.a7,
                        "unit7": tablePR7.u7,
                        "additonal7": tablePR7.add7,
                        "number8": tablePR8.n8,
                        "order8": tablePR8.o8,
                        "des8": tablePR8.d8,
                        "amount8": tablePR8.a8,
                        "unit8": tablePR8.u8,
                        "additonal8": tablePR8.add8,
                        "number9": tablePR9.n9,
                        "order9": tablePR9.o9,
                        "des9": tablePR9.d9,
                        "amount9": tablePR9.a9,
                        "unit9": tablePR9.u9,
                        "additonal9": tablePR9.add9,
                        "number10": tablePR10.n10,
                        "order10": tablePR10.o10,
                        "des10": tablePR10.d10,
                        "amount10": tablePR10.a10,
                        "unit10": tablePR10.u10,
                        "additonal10": tablePR10.add10,
                        "scale1": tablePR1.scale1,
                        "scale2": tablePR2.scale2,
                        "scale3": tablePR3.scale3,
                        "scale4": tablePR4.scale4,
                        "scale5": tablePR5.scale5,
                        "scale6": tablePR6.scale6,
                        "scale7": tablePR7.scale7,
                        "scale8": tablePR8.scale8,
                        "scale9": tablePR9.scale9,
                        "scale10": tablePR10.scale10,
                        "สิ้นเปลือง": isChecked1,
                        "อุปกรณ์-เครื่องมือ": isChecked2,
                        "วัตถุดิบเพื่อการขาย": isChecked3,
                        "วัตถุดิบเพื่อการซ่อมแซม": isChecked4,
                        "วัตถุดิบเพื่อการผลิต": isChecked5,
                        "purchase_req": invoiceNumber,
                        "price1": tablePR1.price1,
                        "price2": tablePR2.price2,
                        "price3": tablePR3.price3,
                        "price4": tablePR4.price4,
                        "price5": tablePR5.price5,
                        "price6": tablePR6.price6,
                        "price7": tablePR7.price7,
                        "price8": tablePR8.price8,
                        "price9": tablePR9.price9,
                        "price10": tablePR10.price10,
                      }).then((value) {
                        sent1();
                        formKey.currentState?.reset();
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: "Submitted",
                          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        );
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return PipelinePurchase();
                        }));
                      });
                    } catch (e) {}
                  } else if (formKey.currentState!.validate() &&
                      selectedValue1 == "ซินโนวิค") {
                    formKey.currentState?.save();
                    try {
                      String invoiceNumber1 = await generateInvoiceNumber1();
                      await _prdetailsCollection.add({
                        "project": selectedValue4,
                        "dropdowncompany": selectedValue1,
                        "dropdowndep": selectedValue2,
                        "dropdownwork": selectedValue3,
                        "fsname": prdetails.fsnames,
                        "date_pr": _dateController.text,
                        "recommend_company": prdetails.recommendcompanypr,
                        "phone": prdetails.phones,
                        "email_pr": prdetails.emailprs,
                        "number1": tablePR1.n1,
                        "order1": tablePR1.o1,
                        "des1": tablePR1.d1,
                        "amount1": tablePR1.a1,
                        "unit1": tablePR1.u1,
                        "additonal1": tablePR1.add1,
                        "number2": tablePR2.n2,
                        "order2": tablePR2.o2,
                        "des2": tablePR2.d2,
                        "amount2": tablePR2.a2,
                        "unit2": tablePR2.u2,
                        "additonal2": tablePR2.add2,
                        "number3": tablePR3.n3,
                        "order3": tablePR3.o3,
                        "des3": tablePR3.d3,
                        "amount3": tablePR3.a3,
                        "unit3": tablePR3.u3,
                        "additonal3": tablePR3.add3,
                        "number4": tablePR4.n4,
                        "order4": tablePR4.o4,
                        "des4": tablePR4.d4,
                        "amount4": tablePR4.a4,
                        "unit4": tablePR4.u4,
                        "additonal4": tablePR4.add4,
                        "number5": tablePR5.n5,
                        "order5": tablePR5.o5,
                        "des5": tablePR5.d5,
                        "amount5": tablePR5.a5,
                        "unit5": tablePR5.u5,
                        "additonal5": tablePR5.add5,
                        "number6": tablePR6.n6,
                        "order6": tablePR6.o6,
                        "des6": tablePR6.d6,
                        "amount6": tablePR6.a6,
                        "unit6": tablePR6.u6,
                        "additonal6": tablePR6.add6,
                        "number7": tablePR7.n7,
                        "order7": tablePR7.o7,
                        "des7": tablePR7.d7,
                        "amount7": tablePR7.a7,
                        "unit7": tablePR7.u7,
                        "additonal7": tablePR7.add7,
                        "number8": tablePR8.n8,
                        "order8": tablePR8.o8,
                        "des8": tablePR8.d8,
                        "amount8": tablePR8.a8,
                        "unit8": tablePR8.u8,
                        "additonal8": tablePR8.add8,
                        "number9": tablePR9.n9,
                        "order9": tablePR9.o9,
                        "des9": tablePR9.d9,
                        "amount9": tablePR9.a9,
                        "unit9": tablePR9.u9,
                        "additonal9": tablePR9.add9,
                        "number10": tablePR10.n10,
                        "order10": tablePR10.o10,
                        "des10": tablePR10.d10,
                        "amount10": tablePR10.a10,
                        "unit10": tablePR10.u10,
                        "additonal10": tablePR10.add10,
                        "scale1": tablePR1.scale1,
                        "scale2": tablePR2.scale2,
                        "scale3": tablePR3.scale3,
                        "scale4": tablePR4.scale4,
                        "scale5": tablePR5.scale5,
                        "scale6": tablePR6.scale6,
                        "scale7": tablePR7.scale7,
                        "scale8": tablePR8.scale8,
                        "scale9": tablePR9.scale9,
                        "scale10": tablePR10.scale10,
                        "สิ้นเปลือง": isChecked1,
                        "อุปกรณ์-เครื่องมือ": isChecked2,
                        "วัตถุดิบเพื่อการขาย": isChecked3,
                        "วัตถุดิบเพื่อการซ่อมแซม": isChecked4,
                        "วัตถุดิบเพื่อการผลิต": isChecked5,
                        "purchase_req": invoiceNumber1,
                        "price1": tablePR1.price1,
                        "price2": tablePR2.price2,
                        "price3": tablePR3.price3,
                        "price4": tablePR4.price4,
                        "price5": tablePR5.price5,
                        "price6": tablePR6.price6,
                        "price7": tablePR7.price7,
                        "price8": tablePR8.price8,
                        "price9": tablePR9.price9,
                        "price10": tablePR10.price10,
                      }).then((value) {
                        sent1();
                        formKey.currentState?.reset();
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: "Submitted",
                          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        );
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return PipelinePurchase();
                        }));
                      });
                    } catch (e) {}
                  }
                },
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[200],
                child: Text(
                  "Submit Form",
                  style: kBodyText,
                ),
              ),
            ),

------------ FloatingActionButton that I want to put sent1() in-------------------
So why email_sender it's doesnt work, anyone try this email_sender? or who has another method to send email in flutter web app?

You will not find a package that sends email without configuring an SMTP server or having some type of account there (for example something like Firebase).
If your app could send emails just like that, it would be a spammers dream.
I am not sure if connecting to an email server could be done from a browser. Normally, you conncet to your backend and the backends sends a mail, since it is way better equipped to deal with any fallout, and the credentials are more secure there, assuming you don't want your users to enter their own credentials into your app.

firebase has only send email for authentication direct from your email that you register in building app
